# gl_LastFragData for blurring the entire scene

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, glsl

So I have a cocos2d iOS app which uses OpenGL ES 2.0. I've got fragment shader where I'm currently just grabbing **`vec4 lastFragColor = gl_LastFragData[0];`** and manipulating it.

But what I'm really wondering if/how I can **access the neighboring fragments** of the current one so that I can do convolution type effects like a **gaussian blur**?

Comment: Not using this extension, `gl_LastFragData` is part of a non-standard extension to GLES created by Apple ([`EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt)). All it really does is allow you to read the fragment that would have served as the `destination` during blending; in other words, it enables a crude form of programmable blending by exposing something that honestly does not belong in fragment shaders to begin with (reading from the framebuffer). For image processing kernels, this extension really will not help.

Comment: I should probably clarify; NV created the original framebuffer_fetch extension (same name, `NV` prefix), but the one you are working with is based on Apple's spec. You only have access to the framebuffer at your fragment's location using this, so in order to do convolution you still have to resort to ping-ponging between different input and output buffers. In GL4 you can effectively do this with image load/store, which largely does away with the need for an extension like this one.

Comment: Ok, so you're suggesting that I don't use this extension and instead go back to a method using CCRenderTexture to render the scene to a texture and work off of that? I thought that this was just a slicker, more efficient and easier to read way to do that. But if it's that limited I won't use it.

Comment: And what about GLES 3? Might that offer any better options?

Comment: Not for what you are trying to do. `gl_LastFragData` is great if you are simply trying to blend your output with the existing framebuffer programmably (e.g. simple things, like compositing). But if you need to fetch from multiple neighboring locations (as you would for a gaussian blur) in the same buffer you are drawing into, you are generally going to need Shader Model 5.0 class hardware.

Comment: You could try rendering to an offscreen object like FBO, and then use it as a texture input to perform what you need, before displaying it.

Comment: In addition to the limitations that Andon describes, for a Gaussian blur you're going to want to render in two passes anyway. Separating the Gaussian kernel into horizontal and vertical passes greatly reduces the number of texture reads per pixel and leads to a huge speedup on iOS devices. You'll also want to take advantage of mid-texel sampling and the hardware accelerated interpolation that provides. gl_LastFragData has some great uses (I'm using it to dramatically expand the dynamic range of a virtual depth buffer), but it's not a great help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You can't grab neighbouring fragments using this gl extension. 
Render to an fbo and use that as an input to render Gaussian blurs instead.